# How to prevent error when parsing this expression "1 day"?

Tags: r, dplyr, nlp, metaprogramming

I have a very specific question about metaprogramming in R.

I successfully coded a function which can understand expressions like `1*days` and use lubridate after that.

But I want to use a more user-friendly, or more natural speaking expression in my final library which would be `1 days`.

Is there a way to prevent this error after executing `eval(1 days)`:
`Error : unexpected symbol in "eval(1 days"`

R does not want me to use space.. Is there any alternative?

Comment: Maybe it exists a function in dplyr I don't know ?!

Comment: Do you mean that the object used by your function has to be '1 day' name?

Comment: There is no way. R doesn't parse a blank space. You'd need to use a character string, replace the blank space and then `parse` the modified string.

Comment: Can you show us the function, how you use it with `1*days` and how you would like to use it with `1 days`?