# How to mimic lisp quoting behavior in R with Non Standard Evaluation?

Tags: r, lisp, metaprogramming, quote

This is a follow-up question to this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67783993/6537892).

Is there a way to fill the gap between this difference in the behavior of R vs Lisp:

#### Lisp

```
(setq foo (quote (1 2)))
```

---

#### R

```
foo <- quote(1 2)
```

which throws the error:
`unexpected symbol in "quote(1 2"`

---

The aim of this trick is to develop an *ad hoc* query language inside of R using tidyeval.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: @RonakShah question edited with purpose explained

Comment: R already has `quote`: it just doesn't have Lisp's list syntax, any more than Lisp has a syntax for lists with commas in it or an infix syntax for expressions.